# Grouping similar token type using Java.

Tags: java

I am trying read a txt file which has following content:

```
-int i1=0;
-int j1=0;

int readvalue;

while ((readvalue = bufferReader.read()) != -1)
{   
    if(readValue  != 10)
    {
         //how can i group them and store itin an array.
   } 

}
```

This code reads each character . I am trying to store these character in an array.
But the thing is i want to store these tokens in a group.
For ex:

```
1.array element 1 -> int
2.array element 2 -> space
3.array element 3-> i1
4.array element 4-> =
5.array element 5-> 0
6.array elementt 6->;
```

Basically i want to group the tokens logically into keywords,digits , spaces, operators etc.
Any idea how can i go ahead with this?

Comment: Map it. E.g. `Token GetToken(String word)`. I'm assuming this is for a lexer part of a parser or similar. You'll want a formal "Token" type as some point, so might as well add it here. (There may be many Token *subtypes* including Value, Keyword, Operator, etc. and each type may reveal additional relevant information about the input word.) Then, instead of using an Array, consider a [(Array)List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) as it allows an increasing size - although in this case it may make the most sense to deal with a "stream" or "generator" approach.

Comment: One solution would be to create a series of regex for each type, then store every value in a hashmap based upon the type determined by regex... but there are probably better ways.

Comment: Sorry i want to build a pure lexer , i dont want to use regex as that will make things very simple

Comment: @user2246674 I want to first store them in some data structure in the form key and value pair and later i would use that key to perform further operations. I want to store it as array(value,key), for ex if i have int then i want to store value-int and key-Letters, similarly for digit 1 , (value-0,key-digit).I would use the key in a later phase.Any suggestion how can go about this?

Comment: You haven't done enough on your own to give you any help. Try out what you're explaining, then come back when you're stuck.